# Why Cant i skip ahead on a MP4 video on a web page i made?

Tags: html, video, mp4

I have an Apache server set up and have made a simple web page,with a video on it.
The video plays, but if i try to skip ahead or behind it freezes up. If i click the pause/play button it will usually go back to the beginning of the video. The video is MP4 format.It might be worth noting that the video is a rather large file as the video I'm trying to play is a hour long. I've tried smaller files and they seem to play fine and i can seek as much as i want. Also if open the web page locally it works, so I'm thinking it has something to do with downloading/buffering the video i just don't know where to start to try and fix it.

Comment: Is your server configured to support the OPTIONS verb and satisfy range requests?

Answer (score 2):

I found this question as I had the same problem, but I wasn't using Apache, but a web server created with Rust/Hyper.

My problem was NOT related to the MOOV atom like described above, but to the fact that this kind of scrolling/skipping through the video requires sending 206 Partial content and appropriate byte ranges with it in response.

This is of course not directly implemented by hyper, so I had to implement it myself.

Answer (score 1):

If it's working with smaller files but not larger ones I would check where the meta data element (MOOV atom) in your mp4 is. By default it's at the end, which means accurating seeking won't be able to happen until the web browser has read the entire file.

You can address this using [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org) to relocate the MOOV atom to the front so the browser is able to request the correct parts of the file (assuming your server is configured to support byte range requests):

```
./ffmpeg -y -i SourceFile.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -movflags faststart DestFile.mp4
```

this will simply re-position the MOOV atom, and copy the audio and video (no reprocessing) - so once the basics are working you might want to look at other optimizations you can do to improve the experience.