# How to play longer videos in html5 player?

Tags: amazon-s3, video, html5-video, large-files

I am trying to play a video file having Size: 2.1 GB, Duration: 06:10:58.17 and Bitrate: 797 kb/s

The file is in S3 storage and after downloading the video plays fine on VLC player desktop but not in html5 player.

In Chrome nothing happens as file doesn't exists:
[image]

In Firefox it keeps on loading and nothing happens:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the length of the video?

Comment: I don't know that.

Comment: Make sure there aren't any other issues. As far as I can tell, there is no problems with playing large videos in the HTML5 video player.

Comment: I have updated my question in firefox after about 15 minutes the fire crashes. I had also tested the video link from s3 in html5 player in w3school

Comment: Is the video local or on a server?

Comment: I have tested the video from S3 link and also on local after downloading it.

Comment: Can you give me the s3 link so I can try it myself?

Comment: Sorry, I can't share the link. But I am open to suggestions.

Comment: have you relocated the MOOV atom to the front of the file (eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584700/why-cant-i-skip-ahead-on-a-mp4-video-on-a-web-page-i-made/51586102#51586102). Also, if after downloading it's not playing in the browser have you confirmed that the encoding is acceptable for the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The videos were created by Wowza and all the videos having duration more than 3 hours were not playing in html5 player. So, I have used wowza player to play these videos and it's working fine.